# Customize flask-security's @auth_token_required unauthorized response

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I'm trying flask for the first time and I'm trying to create a rest api with token-based authentication.

Everything's going fine except that I cannot customize the unauthorized response returned by `@auth_token_required` which is this default message:

> **Unauthorized**
>
> The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL
>   requested. You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g. a bad
>   password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the
>   credentials required.

I would like it to return a json response which may look something like:

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Unauthorized message"
}
```

So far I have tried overriding `unauthorized_handler` using:

```
@app.login_manager.unauthorized_handler
def unauthorized():
    // code goes here
```

But it doesn't seem to work for `@auth_token_required` decorator.

Answer (score 1):

Refering to the response by pip, Flask Security internally uses flask login for its implementation callback.Hence when we register a callback handler with Flask security, we get call stack exceeded response.

**app.security.unauthorized_handler(unauth_handler)**

Hence instead please register with Flask login

**app.login_manager.unauthorized_handler(unauth_handler)**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I have; it seems to work!

```
import json

from flask import Reponse


def unauth_handler():
    return Response(json.dumps({'unauthorized': True}), 401)

app.security.unauthorized_handler(unauth_handler)
```

Here is a more complete example of where this is being called just in case that has something to do with the error below.

```
def setup_app(app):
    config(app)

    # database init, allows the DB to be available in core but setup per application.
    db.init_app(app)

    # bcrypt, again available from core.
    bcrypt.init_app(app)

    # setup assets
    app.assets_env = Environment(app)

    # login system
    app.user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
    app.security = security.init_app(app, app.user_datastore)

    def unauth_handler():
        return Response(ejson.dumps({'unauthorized': True}), 401)

    app.security.unauthorized_handler(unauth_handler)

    logger(app)
    jinja_filters(app)
    assets(app)
    modules(app)
```

And then I pass in the app into the setup function in init.

Comment: Tried this code and got error maximu call stack exceeded.

Comment: Hmmm.  Let me look at my code again, I seem to remember changing it.

Answer (score 0):

updating the above answer

```
from flask import response, jsonify
from flask_security.decorators import _get_unauthorized_response

user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security()
security_state = security.init_app(app, user_datastore)

def unauth_handler():
    if request.is_json:
        return jsonify({'status': False, 'message': 'Unauthorized!'}), 401, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    else:
        return _get_unauthorized_response()

security_state.unauthorized_handler(unauth_handler)
```